# Derivatives And Chain Rule Doubt.

Tags: derivatives

For some function,

$x = f(t)$

$y = g(t)$

If we wish to calculate second order derivative of y with respect to x would it be right to approach in the following manner:

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{d^2y}{dt^2}.\frac{dt^2}{dx^2}$
?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: What does $dt^2/dx^2$ even mean?

Comment: $x=f(t)$ and $y=f(t)$ imply $x=y$.

Comment: You can use double dollar signs to get displayed equations, which are easier to read, especially if they include fractions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dx^2}
&=&
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\left(\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\right)
\\
&=&
\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\right)\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\left(\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\right)
\\
&=&
\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm dt^2}\cdot\left(\frac{\mathrm dt}{\mathrm dx}\right)^2+\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dt}\cdot\frac{\mathrm d^2t}{\mathrm dx^2}\;.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I'm sorry, I rolled back your formatting edit; the result hurt my eyes! :-)

Comment: @GrahamKemp: I did put the multiplication dots back in that you'd added, though; I guess they help to emphasize the difference between differentiation and multiplication.